What does "look behind the mirrors" mean in the context?
I was reading a book called "Feeling Good: The New Mood Therapy by David D. Burns". Here is a part of the book,

When you are depressed, you
possess the remarkable ability to believe, and to get the people around you to
believe, things which have no basis in reality. As a therapist, it is my job to penetrate your illusion, to teach you
how to look behind the mirrors so you can see how you have been
fooling yourself.

I'm wondering what does "look behind the mirrors" mean in the second sentence. I asked ChatGPT and here is the answer,

The phrase "look behind the mirrors" is a metaphor. It suggests that the patient is seeing a distorted version of reality, like looking into a funhouse mirror that changes and exaggerates appearances. The therapist's job is to help the patient see beyond these distortions—behind the mirrors—to understand the true, undistorted reality. This means helping the patient recognize and challenge their false beliefs and negative thoughts, gaining a clearer, more accurate perspective on themselves and their circumstances.

Note that, the distortion of thoughts is mentioned several times in the book before this sentence. Although this suggested metaphor makes sense to me, there is no reference to "funhouse mirrors" in the original text. It just used "mirrors". So I doubt that this is the intended meaning.

Edit:
I just noticed that before the quoted text, the author tells a story about his amazement as a child at how a magician creates illusions. Then he says

Now I know that his ability as an illusionist was no greater than that
of the average depressed patient. That includes you.

And then the quoted text at the top of my post. At the time I posted this question, I didn't pay enough attention to this part because I didn't think it was relevant. Now I think that looking behind the mirror might be relevant to some of the tricks that magicians use to create illusions (which, unfortunately, I'm not familiar with!).

I've not read the book but I'd guess the author is telling you to look more deeply into yourself and not just consider the outward appearance you see in a mirror. But "look behind the mirrors" isn't a standard English idiom so I don't think this is on-topic; the metaphor would be the same in any language.

What @StuartF: Look behind the mirror is a fairly daft metaphoric usage (with relatively little currency), since what's actually behind the mirror is usually the wall. It makes much more sense to talk about metaphorically looking under the surface / below the skin for true underlying characteristics.

My above chart overstated the prevalence, even though behind the mirror practically flatlines by comparison with more common alternatives. As this chart shows, the cited plural version is even less common.

@FumbleFingers Thanks for the information! Please check my edit, in the context of magician's tricks I believe one can make sense out of the "behind the mirrors".

Obviously you can "make sense" of the intended usage (figure out what the imho incompetent writer is trying to say). But it's not actually a very sensible choice of phrasing, so i certainly wouldn't encourage anyone learning English to copy it!


No, it's not really an established phrase. And yes, it's confusing.

So we can't really give a very good answer to "what it means," but for a learner, it's worth establishing that much. The overall meaning can be guessed from context, and it has a similarity to several other common phrases and metaphors:

My first thought was "smoke and mirrors". This idiom comes from sleight-of-hand and "magic" illusions, in which cleverly placed mirrors might fool an audience into thinking they've seen something they didn't (like someone appearing to levitate, when in fact a mirror stands in the way of a supporting structure, and reflects the same color as the surroundings). There is often an implication with this idiom that the "smoke and mirrors" are not merely a misrepresentation but a distraction. In this sense the passage would mean "The 'realities' you're creating are an avoidance tactic, and we can help dismiss them and deal with what really matters."
A similar phrase is actually a quote from The Wizard of Oz. The Wizard appears as a terrifying giant head, but it is revealed that this is an elaborate mechanical illusion, and that the real Wizard is an ordinary man operating it while concealed behind a curtain. When a dog pulls aside the curtain and reveals him, he makes a final effort to continue the illusion by making the head roar "Pay no attention to that man behind the curtain!" This line is often quoted to the point of becoming its own idiom, to mean "Someone wishes to draw attention away from their role in this matter." Some sense of this usage might be combined with "smoke and mirrors" to explain the use of the word "behind" in "look behind the mirrors": I.e. expose and "look behind" the illusions that have been covering up the real mechanisms.
The metaphor of "funhouse mirrors" has already been mentioned. This metaphor talks about distorting a view of reality, but the "behind" part makes little sense here.


Thanks for the answer! I updated my post please see my edit.

@Etemon Yeah, I feel like that makes me more confident in my answer. Though if I were the author's editor I'd still recommend they make it clearer.

Oh true, now I see it is related to your first thought.

ChatGPT is exactly correct. A "funhouse mirror" is one which makes you look very different than reality, and here is metaphorically linked to how depression distorts your view of yourself. The original text does not explicitly mention a funhouse, but it's an idiomatic description of a mirror that distorts, and and apt extension of the mirror metaphor here.
That said, I find "look behind the mirror" to be a poor attempt at an idiom in the first place, as you don't see your true self when looking behind a distorted mirror, you just see nothing. It seems like it may be a self-introspective bastardization of "look behind the curtain", meaning to understand the truth about something.
In light of the edited question, I suppose the turn of phrase makes a bit more sense in the context of a magician's illusion, where there may indeed be a hidden reality concealed behind the mirror.

Even an 'ordinary' mirror produces what physicists call a virtual image - one that doesn't exist, but is just an effect of the light. But 'look behind the mirror' is at best a mixed metaphor.

Thanks for the answer! I updated my post please see my edit.
